# Adding react.js reference to existing .net mvc project

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, reactjs

I added references ReactJS.NET(MVC 4 and 5) to my .Net MVC 4 project, but getting this strange exception that i cannot figure out to correct it:

```
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace: 


[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +9
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +70
React.<>c.<InitializeIoC>b__2_0(Assembly assembly) +12
System.Linq.<SelectManyIterator>d__1`2.MoveNext() +188
System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +170
React.Initializer.InitializeIoC(Func`2 requestLifetimeRegistration) +275
React.Web.WebInitializer.Initialize() +43

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments,     Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +192
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +136
WebActivatorEx.BaseActivationMethodAttribute.InvokeMethod() +73
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods(Boolean designerMode) +350
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run() +78

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]

System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +613
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +141
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String  preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,  PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Run on type WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9920756
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Comment: @nihilus. Are you by any chance using BenTaylor.BundleTransformer?

Comment: Could you please try looking at the `LoaderExceptions` property on the exception to see what the actual error message is?

Comment: I am receiving the following LoadException after updating Mvc4 components to 3.0.0.0
{System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c608b2a8cc9e4472' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c608b2a8cc9e4472'